# Maven Build Lifecycle: validate

Tags: java, maven

In the build lifecycle in maven, I encountered the *validate* phase described as *validate the project is correct and all necessary information is available to complete a build*
1. what are the check points for a project to be ***correct***?
2. what are these ***necessary information*** that needs to be available in completing a build?
Can you provide example for both?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Short Answer

1. It's up to you
2. It's up to you

## Long Answer

Why? Because by default (ie. on a clean, empty project with no user-defined plugin goals), `mvn validate` does nothing.

Why? A build phase is comprised of plugin goals. No goals for a phase? The phase does nothing.

From the the [Build Lifecycle Basics](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html#Build_Lifecycle_Basics) section of the [Introduction to the Build Lifecycle](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html) guide:

> Furthermore, a build phase can also have zero or more goals bound to
>   it. If a build phase has no goals bound to it, that build phase will
>   not execute. But if it has one or more goals bound to it, it will
>   execute all those goals

This means that unless you declare a plugin goal that is bound to the `validate` phase, the `validate` phase will do nothing.

The definition that you've found isn't saying that something **will** happen during that build phase, but rather **if** you want an action to occur in that phase (ie. step) of the build lifecycle, then that is the phase to bind the goal to.

> validate the project is correct and all necessary information is available to complete a build

This is a guideline for how to organize your plugins so that they execute efficiently and in the expected order, at the expected time.

For example, say we have a new, empty Maven project with no build plugins defined. If we were to run `mvn verify`, Maven will click through each build phase up to and including the verify phase. We might expect the output to be empty, however there are default [Built-in Lifecycle Bindings](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html#Built-in_Lifecycle_Bindings), so our output will include all default goals:

```
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.5:resources (default-resources) @ MavenTest ---
...
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2:compile (default-compile) @ MavenTest ---
...
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.5:testResources (default-testResources) @ MavenTest ---
...
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ MavenTest ---
...
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.10:test (default-test) @ MavenTest ---
```

For you, a metric of a "correct" project may be that the styling of the code meets some criteria, so say we add the [maven-checkstyle-plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-checkstyle-plugin/) to our otherwise empty Maven project:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-checkstyle-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.17</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>verify-style</id>
            <phase>validate</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>check</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

...and then re-run `mvn verify`:

```
[INFO] --- maven-checkstyle-plugin:2.17:check (verify-style) @ MavenTest ---
...
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.5:resources (default-resources) @ MavenTest ---
...
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2:compile (default-compile) @ MavenTest ---
...
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.5:testResources (default-testResources) @ MavenTest ---
...
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ MavenTest ---
...
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.10:test (default-test) @ MavenTest ---
```

Because we have declared a plugin and told it to execute as part of the `validate` phase, the `validate` phase will now actually do something.

To further illustrate the point, we could remove the plugin again and run `mvn validate`, and see that there is nothing that happens, because there are no default bindings for the `validate` phase:

```
C:\workspace\MavenTest>mvn validate
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building MavenTest 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 0.078s
[INFO] Finished at: Thu Jun 30 11:56:54 CDT 2016
[INFO] Final Memory: 2M/15M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

As for an example of checking that "necessary information" is available, one situation may be validating that certain config files in a project have certain information. Again, that is really up to you based on your use case.

Comment: splendid explanation, thanks; it is based upon your configuration what those criteria would mean